# Ordering by a boolean attribute in a has_many scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, associations

I have a model `Restaurant` that has many `MenuGroups`. The `MenuGroup` model has a `primary` attribute. I'd like to order my menus in ascending order, where any menu marked as primary would come first. Strangely my scope has no affect:

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :menu_groups, -> { order(primary: :asc) }, dependent: :destroy
end

class MenuGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: How are you using that scope? Do you have NULL values as well?

Comment: I'm using this as the default order for how menu_groups are retrieved when doing something like: `restaurant.menu_groups`. No NULL values.

Comment: Check your `log/development.log` to make sure the generated query includes the correct `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Just checked. Doesn't look like it's included.

Comment: Would it be worth defining a separate scope on `MenuGroup` just for the order clause and then appending that in any queries where that matters? Baking them into the `has_many` relationship can cause problems.

Comment: That's possible but just wondering how to incorporate it in how I'm accessing the menu_groups being that the only way I'm retrieving these objects is through the restaurant collection (they're not standalone). What problems are you foreseeing?

Comment: It's mostly that you should separate "relations" from decorators like "scopes". If a relationship comes with too much baggage it can make code that uses that relationship behave in unpredictable ways. Ordering shouldn't be a function of the relationship, but something the code using that relationship explicitly asks for.

Comment: The way you declare the relation seems to be ok. Maybe it is a problem with the server or the console you are trying that code on. I don't know, is a long shot.

Comment: Is there a default scope somewhere? I'd agree with @tadman that an explicit ORDER BY is generally a better idea (possibly even through an extension on the `has_many`) but a `restaurant.menu_groups` call should be including that `#order` call. What does the SQL end up looking like? Is `restaurant.rb` not be reloaded?

Comment: There's no default order atm. I thought creating those was frowned upon in the rails community?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's still the case in Rails 5.2 because I make a habit of avoiding default order conditions, but in earlier versions it could cause unpredictable results if two conflicting order clauses were being applied.

Comment: The code seems ok, but if you want primary (true) menugroups to be first, shouldn't you order descending? Anyway, I see now that you say there is no ORDER BY present in the generated query, please answer the following questions, they might give some more clue: what data type is the column, what db and how exactly do you call the relation in the code?